# How can I use the Google Admin Directory API from Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

I have an app running on Google App Engine that I have turned on Cloud Integration so that I can use the Admin SDK.  In my Google Apps console's Manage API Access section I used the following scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly

for the client name: MYID.apps.googleusercontent.com

So, I thought I could simply do something like this:

```
ArrayList scopes = new ArrayList();
scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly");
scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");


AppIdentityCredential appCredential = new AppIdentityCredential(scopes);


Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, appCredential)
            .setApplicationName("MY APP")
            .build();
Directory.Users.List list = directory.users().list();
list.setDomain("MYDOMAIN.com");

Users users = (Users) list.execute();
```

I end up receiving 404 errors, so I was wondering what I am missing for the configuration?

Comment: Have you enabled Admin SDK in API console?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled Admin SDK after turning on the Cloud Integration from the Google App Engine console.

Comment: Hi, have you found what's the problem ?

Comment: Not yet. But I have not looked into it since my last comment.